# Erlang Doesn't Warn About Unused Function Argument

Tags: erlang, pattern-matching

If I declare a function

```
test(A) -> 3.
```

Erlang generates a warning about variable `A` not being used. However the definition

```
isEqual(X,X) -> 1.
```

Doesn't produce any warning but

```
isEqual(X,X) -> 1;
isEqual(X,Y) -> 0.
```

again produces a warning but only for the second line.

Comment: Probably because `X` _is_ being used here, as Erlang compares the first argument with the second argument for equality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why that doesn't generate a warning is because in the second case you are asserting (through pattern matching), by using the same variable name, that the first and second arguments to `isEqual/2` have the same value. So you are actually using the value of the argument.

It might help to understand better if we look at the Core Erlang code produced from `is_equal/2`. You can get `.core` source files by compiling your `.erl` file in the following way: `erlc +to_core pattern.erl` (see here for [`pattern.erl`](https://gist.github.com/jfacorro/ff4680b79e5ccd4e9fdf13d7754ce090)).

This will produce a `pattern.core` file that will look something like this (`module_info/[0,1]` functions removed):

```
module 'pattern' ['is_equal'/2]
  attributes []

'is_equal'/2 = fun (_cor1,_cor0) ->
                   case <_cor1,_cor0> of
                     %% Line 5
                     <X,_cor4> when call 'erlang':'=:=' (_cor4, X) ->
                       1
                     %% Line 6
                     <X,Y> when 'true' ->
                       0
                   end
```

As you can see, each function clause from `is_equal/2` in the `.erl` source code gets translated to a `case` clause in Core Erlang. `X` does get used in the first clause since it needs to be compared to the other argument. On the other hand neither `X` or `Y` are used in the second clause.

Comment: I think it should still generate the warning because as a user I might have forgotten to use X on the RHS. If I understand correctly, you are saying is that the pattern matching code for binding (X,X) will have additional constraints that use X and that are not present in the code for binding(X,Y) in the (edited) definition of `isEqual()`.

Comment: @farhanhubble I added some more information to the answer.